# Let $K \subset (X,d)$ compact, $F$ closed and $F \cap K = \emptyset$. Prove that there exists $r>0$ s.t $\{x \in X: d(x,K) < r \} \cap F =\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

We proved this in my class the following way:

Since $F$ is closed, then $\forall x \in K \ \exists \ r_x / B(x, r_x) \cap F = \emptyset$.
Taking the open cover $\{B(x, \dfrac{r_x}{2}) \}_{x \in K}$, we can extract a finite subcover $\{B(x, \dfrac{r_{x_i}}{2}) \}_{1 \leq i \leq m}$ since K is compact. Now, taking $r = \min \{\dfrac{r_{x_i}}{2}\}$, if $y \in \{x \in X: d(x,K) < r \}$ then $d(y,K) < r \implies y \in B(x,r)$ for some $x \in K$, from which we can conclude that $y \notin F$.

Now, my instructor told us that the proof would fail if, instead of taking the open cover with $\dfrac{r_x}{2}$, we just took it with $r_x$ (he didn't elaborate at the time and I didn't pay much attention to it then). Anyway, i'm failing to see this. Taking $r_x$ and then $r = \min \{r_{xi}\}$ also guarantees that if $d(y,K) < r$ then $y \notin F$, doesn't it? Since that would also imply $y \in B(x,r) \subset B(x, r_x)$ for some $x \in K$.
Please correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion $B(x,r)\subseteq B(x,r_x)$ is not true in general. Indeed, $r$ is only the minimum of the finitely many $r_{x_1},\dotsc,r_{x_n}$, but for an arbitrary $x\in K$, you cannot say whether $r$ is larger or smaller than $r_x$. For a concrete example, consider $X=\mathbb{R}$, $K=[0,1]$ and $Y=\{2\}$. You can take as cover the cover of $K$ by a single open ball $B(1/2,3/2)$, which would lead to the choice $r=3/2$, but $2\in\{x\in X\mid d(x,K)<3/2\}$.

Comment: So how does taking $r = \min\{ \dfrac{r_{x_i}}{2}\}$ solve the problem? Since if $y \in B(x,r)$ then $d(x,F) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,F) < r + d(y,F)$. But how is it that $r < d(x,F)$ for some arbitrary $x$?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to get at there. The point we want to arrive at is that $d(y,K)<r$ implies $y\not\in F$. Since $K$ is compact, there is an $x\in K$ s.t. $d(y,K)=d(y,x)$. Since $x\in K$, there is an $i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, s.t. $x\in B(x_i,r_{x_i}/2)$. Now $d(y,x_i)\le d(y,x)+d(x,x_i)<r+r_{x_i}/2\le r_{x_i}$, where the last inequality is by definition of $r$. This inequality just means that $y\in B(x_i,r_{x_i})$ and this ball was disjoint from $F$ by construction.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot to use that $x \in K$ means that $x \in B(x_i, \dfrac{r_{x_i}}{2})$. I was trying to get to $0 < d(y,F)$ in my last comment.